# How to close NHibenrate session when using the ThreadPool?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, nhibernate, thread-safety

Since threads are reused over and over by the ThreadPool I can't tell when to close NHibernate sessions for each thread to release used up resources.

Should I spawn my own threads (to ensure they are unique) or there is a better way to do this using the ThreadPool?

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see the problem. You might to have to elaborate or add some code in your question.

Each thread has it's own method. Simply allocate the session in the beginning of the method and clean it up in the end.  The same applies when you are using a thread pool thread.

Don't forget to wrap all thread code in a try/catch, or your application will crash if an exception is unhandled.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have it set up so that there is one session per thread. This is probably the easiest way to make sure that you don't run into issues where you have a thread terminating a session that is in use by another thread.